# Как повысить повторность использования кода, при наследовании класса

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода, наследование

У меня есть базовый абстрактный класс Object, его наследник Human.

У него два своих наследника.

1. Student - в нем обрабатываю по каким предметам какие оценки, и на этом основании высчитываю их высчитываю стипендию.
2. Teacher - здесь схожая схема, предметы и кол-во учебных часов. На основе часов высчитывается ЗП. От Teacher наследую HeadTeacher. Он должен делать все то же самое, только его ЗП на 60% больше.

Я это организовал, но, кажется, что все это криво и можно было сделать более грамотно. Поэтому прошу помощи.
Т.к. отличий HeadTeacher от Teacher малы, то добавлю, что потом планируется добавления поля массива указателей на объекты Teacher. (Заместители заведующего)

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <strings.h>
#include <ctime>
 
using namespace std;
 
 
#define MAX_SUBJECTS 10
#define MAX_STR 256
 
#define VALID_SUBJ(subjectID) (subjectID >= 0 && subjectID <= MAX_SUBJECTS - 1)
#define VALID_GRADE(grade) (grade >= 0 && grade <= 5)
 
/*
 
    Иерархия: Object -> Human -> Student
                            \
                             -> Teacher -> HeadTeacher
 
*/
 
//Базовый класс
class Object
{
public:
    
    //обязательно деструктор должен быть виртуальным!
    virtual ~Object() { cout << "dtor Object" << endl; }
        
    virtual void printAbout() const = 0; //теперь класс Object считается виртуальным, его экземпляры создавать нельзя    
};
 
 
// Родительский класс
class Human: public Object
{
    char fio[MAX_STR];
    int yearBirth;
    int basicPay = 1000;
 
    
    
public:
    
    Human(const char* fio, int yearBirth): yearBirth(yearBirth)
    {
        strcpy(this->fio, fio);
    }
    
    ~Human() { cout << "dtor Human" << endl; }
    
    const char* getFIO() const { return fio; }
    
    int getBasicPay() const { return basicPay; }
 
    
    int getAge() const
    {
        time_t t = time(NULL);
        return (localtime(&t)->tm_year + 1900) - yearBirth;
    }
    
    virtual void printAbout() const override
    {
        cout << "Human::printAbout(...)" << endl;
        //Object::printAbout(); // можно вызвать реализацию по-умолчанию если она определена
        cout << getFIO() << " возраст: " << getAge() << " лет." << endl;
    }
};
 
// Класс - потомок 1
class Student: public Human
{
    int grades[MAX_SUBJECTS];
 
    
    void printGrades() const
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBJECTS; ++i)
        {
            cout << "Предмет №" << i + 1 << ": ";
            
            if( grades[i] )
                cout << " оценка " << grades[i];  
            else
                cout << "нет оценки";  
                
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    
public:
    
    Student(const char* fio, int yearBirth) : Human(fio, yearBirth)
    {
        memset(&grades, 0, MAX_SUBJECTS * sizeof(int));
    }
    
    
    void setGrade(int subjectId, int grade)
    {
        if(!VALID_SUBJ(subjectId) || !VALID_GRADE(grade)) return;
        
        grades[subjectId] = grade;
    }
    
    int getGrade(int subjectId) const
    {
        if(!VALID_SUBJ(subjectId)) return 0;
        
        return grades[subjectId];
    }
 
    
    float getFullPay() const 
    {
        float k;
        int countMarks[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBJECTS; ++i)
        {
            switch (grades[i])
            {
                case 1: {countMarks[0] += 1; break;}
                case 2: {countMarks[1] += 1; break;}
                case 3: {countMarks[2] += 1; break;}
                case 4: {countMarks[3] += 1; break;}
                case 5: {countMarks[4] += 1; break;}
            }
        }
        if (countMarks[1] > 0) {k = 0.0;}
        else if (countMarks[2] > 0) {k = 0.5;}
        else if (countMarks[3] > 0) {k = 1;}
        else if (countMarks[4] > 0) {k = 1.5;}
        return getBasicPay() * k;
     
     }
    
    virtual void printAbout() const override
    {
        cout << "Student::printAbout(...)" << endl;
        
        cout << getFullPay() << endl;
        
        Human::printAbout(); 
        printGrades();
    }
};
 
 
// Класс - потомок 2
class Teacher: public Human
{
    int subjects[MAX_SUBJECTS];
 
    void printSubjects() const
    {
        cout << "Ведет предметы:" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBJECTS; ++i)
        {
            cout << "Предмет № " << i + 1 << ": ";
            if(subjects[i]) 
                cout << "Часов: " << subjects[i];
            else
                cout << "Не ведет."; 
            cout << endl;
        }
            
 
    }
    
public:
    
    Teacher(const char* fio, unsigned short yearBirth) : Human(fio, yearBirth)
    {
        memset(&subjects, 0, MAX_SUBJECTS * sizeof(int));
    }
    
    virtual ~Teacher() { cout << "dtor Teacher" << endl; }
    
    void setSubject(int subjectId, int subjectHour)
    {
        if(!VALID_SUBJ(subjectId)) return;
        subjects[subjectId] = subjectHour;
    }
    
    int getSubject(int subjectId) const
    {
        if(!VALID_SUBJ(subjectId)) return 0;
        return subjects[subjectId];
    }
    
    float getFullPay() const 
    {
        int sumHour = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBJECTS; ++i)
        {
            if(subjects[i]) { sumHour += subjects[i];}
        }
        return getBasicPay() * sumHour / 60;
     
     }
    
    virtual void printAbout() const override
    {
        cout << "Teacher::printAbout(...)" << endl;
        cout << getFullPay() << endl;
        Human::printAbout(); 
        printSubjects();
    }
};
 
 
class HeadTeacher: virtual public Teacher
{
    int subjects[MAX_SUBJECTS];
    
    void printSubjects() const
    {
        cout << "Ведет предметы:" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBJECTS; ++i)
        {
            cout << "Предмет № " << i + 1 << ": ";
            if(subjects[i]) 
                cout << "Часов: " << subjects[i];
            else
                cout << "Не ведет."; 
            cout << endl;
        }
            
 
    }
    
    
    public:
    
    HeadTeacher(const char* fio, unsigned short yearBirth) : Teacher(fio, yearBirth)
    {
        memset(&subjects, 0, MAX_SUBJECTS * sizeof(int));
    }
    
    virtual ~HeadTeacher() { cout << "dtor HeadTeacher" << endl; }
    
    void setSubject(int subjectId, int subjectHour)
    {
        if(!VALID_SUBJ(subjectId)) return;
        subjects[subjectId] = subjectHour;
    }
    
    int getSubject(int subjectId) const
    {
        if(!VALID_SUBJ(subjectId)) return 0;
        return subjects[subjectId];
    }
    
    float getFullPay() const 
    {
        int sumHour = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBJECTS; ++i)
        {
            if(subjects[i]) { sumHour += subjects[i];}
        }
        return getBasicPay() * sumHour / 60 * 1.6;
     
     }
    
    virtual void printAbout() const override
    {
        cout << "HeadTeacher::printAbout(...)" << endl;
        cout << getFullPay() << endl;
        Human::printAbout(); 
        printSubjects();
    }
    
};
 
 
void printAboutObject(const Object* object)
{
    object->printAbout();
}
 
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    system("chcp 1251");
 
    //Object objAbstract; //[Error] cannot declare variable 'objAbstract' to be of abstract type 'Object'
    
    Student student("Петр", 2001);
    student.setGrade(3, 4);
    student.setGrade(5, 5);
    student.setGrade(9, 4);
    student.printAbout();
    cout << endl;
    
    Teacher teacher("Владимир Алексеевич", 1963);
    teacher.setSubject(3, 10);
    teacher.setSubject(6, 15);
    teacher.setSubject(8, 20);
    teacher.printAbout();
    cout << endl << "------------------------------" << endl << endl;
    
    
    HeadTeacher hteacher("Петр Алексеевич", 1963);
    hteacher.setSubject(3, 10);
    hteacher.setSubject(6, 15);
    hteacher.setSubject(8, 20);
    hteacher.printAbout();
    cout << endl << "------------------------------" << endl << endl;
    
    
    Teacher* obj = new Teacher("Владимир Алексеевич", 1963);
    obj->setSubject(1, 10);
    printAboutObject(obj);
    delete obj;
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае метод для повышения повторности использования кода - при возможности переносить код как можно выше по иерархии. Т.е. если можно какой-то функционал реализовать в более верхнем классе в иерархии наследования, тогда этот функционал будет доступен в классах-наследниках сразу, либо с минимальными доработками.
Например для вашей задачи - первый в иерархии класс `Object` у вас пустой, просто интерфейс скорее всего для того, чтобы можно было использовать указатели на `Object` для ссылки на объекты любых классов-наследников. Добавьте сюда какой-нибудь функционал по управлению объектами - возможности сериализации например, или управлением какими-нибудь ресурсами. Минимальный пример - добавьте какой-нибудь `ID`, для использования в технических целях. Он есть практически везде - в базах данных, коллекциях и т.д. У вас ведь 1 объект == 1 человеку.
Далее идет класс `Human`. То же самое - добавьте функционал, который можно использовать для любого человека, независимо от того, преподаватель он или студент, директор или зам. Например ссылки на персональную страницу, или функционал отправки служебных писем или ещё что-то. И этот функционал станет доступен сразу всем наследникам.

> От Teacher наследую HeadTeacher. Он должен делать все то же самое, только его ЗП на 60% больше.

А вот это уже не совсем то - при наследовании желательно добавлять какой-то функционал или изменять поведение, а не просто зарплата больше. Зарплата есть и там и там, нет смысла наследовать. Вы должны подумать, чем `HeadTeacher` функционально отличается. Например у него есть какие-то дополнительные обязанности - какое-то особенное взаимодействие с условным "Минобразования" и т.д.

> Т.к. отличий HeadTeacher от Teacher малы, то добавлю, что потом планируется добавления поля массива указателей на объекты Teacher. (Заместители заведующего)

И вот это тоже не совсем "красиво". Иметь признак что кто-то является замом кого-то конечно надо, но проще держать массив тех самых `ID` из класса `Object`.
В любом случае, здесь речь идет не о "правильности", а больше о "красоте". Если программа правильно работает - значит она правильная. А вот от того насколько  она "красивая" зависит накладные расходы на её поддержку и развитие. Хорошо спроектированная система легче поддаётся внесению изменений/дополнений, без необходимости перелопачивать весь предыдущий код вручную.
Это если попытаться ответить на Ваш общий вопрос. Но при разработке крупных систем часто наследование не лучший механизм. Об этом почитайте литературу на темы "Архитектура ИС", "Проектирование ИС", "Паттерны проектирования".